# Ввести последовательность чисел без массива и определить номер последнего отрицательного элемента

Tags: c++, циклы, while, числовые-последовательности

Проблемы возникшие с решением:

1. Как остановить данный цикл, при вводе последнего числа последовательности?
2. Выводится первый отрицательный элемент, а нужен последний.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить код.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int n = 1, x = 0;
    std::cout << "Enter the sequence: ";
    while (std::cin >> x) {
        std::cin >> x;
        if (x >= 0)
            n++;
    }
    std::cout << n;
}
```

Comment: (1) нажать Ctrl+Z, потом enter. (2) Во-первых, второй `std::cin >> x;` - лишний. Во-вторых, `n++;` считает, сколько всего неотрицательных чисел, а не номер какого-то из них. Чтобы был номер, вам нужно `n++` делать для всех чисел вообще, а для отрицательных - копировать его в еще одну переменную, которую потом печатать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int no = 0, nno = 0, x;
    while (cin >> x) {
        no++;
        if (x < 0) nno = no;
        }
    cout << nno;
    }
```

Просто считаете все числа, и если отрицательное - перезаписываете его номер.

Прекратить цикл можно или введя Ctrl-Z (в Windows), или введя **не** число.